# Replace text values in a vector

Tags: r

Here's my data :

```
dataset <- c("h", "H", "homme", "masculin", "f", "femme", "épouse")
```

How can I replace text values of the vector like :

- "femme" -> "f"
- "épouse" ->"f"
- "Homme"-> "h"
- "masculin" -> "h"

What I tried for  "femme" -> "f"

```
test_out <- sapply(dataset, switch,
         "f"="femme")
test_out
```

Expected result :

```
  "h"        "h"        "h"    "masculin" "f"        "f"    "f"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `gsub` with regular expressions:

```
 dataset = gsub("^((?!h).*)$", "f", gsub("^((h|H|m).*)$", "h", dataset), perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: It works great @juan